# MYsql - Get average time between a start and stop time across many rows

Tags: mysql, average

I have the following SQL and PHP that doesnt seem to be giving me the right numbers. (VERY high numbers)

I have a lot of rows with a start time and an end timestamp.
Im looking to get the average time between those two times.

Ie: 2 hours, 3 minutes, 46 seconds.

This is what I have.

```
SELECT AVG(tmp.dd) AS timetook
  FROM 
     ( SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(timeclosed, timeanswered)) AS dd 
         FROM logs 
        WHERE timeclosed > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
     ) tmp;
```

Am I going about this the completely wrong way? Anything obviously wrong here?

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                        $timetoclose = $row['timetook'];
                                        $hours = floor($timetoclose / 3600);
                                        $mins = floor($timetoclose / 60 % 60);
                                        $secs = floor($timetoclose % 60);
                                        $timetoclose = sprintf('%02d Hour(s), %02d Minute(s), %02d Second(s)', $hours, $mins, $secs);
                                }
```

Cheers
G

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong in your query. Is the average of "2 hours" is THAT high? Over 24 hours, it doesnt look incorrect to me. Keep  in my mind that with AVG, if you have a few rows with a high number, it increase everything. Maybe you should use MEDIAN instead, not available in MySQL but can mimick it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(minute, start_time, end_time)) / COUNT(*) AS avg_minutes
FROM your_table
```

try this query.